# How do I reattach a piece of door trim?

Tags: doors, trim

The side trim of our doors came apart. I didn't see any screw holes anywhere. What is the best way to reattach it?

[image]

Comment: Does the inside surface feel a bit rubbery?  If so then they used some type of caulking, probably silicon.

Comment: Coloured trim(small) nails would probably be best if the supporting piece is wood(like).  If metal/stone or plastic, then clean the old stuff off and re-apply.

Comment: depends how long should it last